# jxTable Initial sort order

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I'd like to initially sort a table. I tried following code:

```
tableModel = createTableModel(model);
rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tableModel);
rowSorter.setSortKeys(Arrays.asList(getDefaultSort()));
rowSorter.sort();


final JXTable table = new JXTable();
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
table.setRowSorter(createSorter());
```

When I click the default sort column it works fine, so there seems to be no problem with the actual sorting. But the UI doesn't sort initially with the above code, the UI shows no sort indicator (that small triangle in the column header). What do I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that the RowSorter is set before the TableModel is set. I had this problem once.

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultRowSorter.toggleSortOrder( column );
```

Comment: @morpheus05, Works fine for me. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. First try it with a JTable to see if the standard classes work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do like this Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SortTable extends JFrame{
  protected JTable table = new JTable();

  protected TabModel tabmodel;

   public SortTable() {
    super();
    setSize(500, 200);

    tabmodel = new TabModel();

     table.setModel(tabmodel);

    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    header.setUpdateTableInRealTime(true);
    header.addMouseListener(tabmodel.new ColumnListener(table));
    header.setReorderingAllowed(true);

    JScrollPane ps = new JScrollPane();
    ps.getViewport().add(table);
    getContentPane().add(ps, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    };
    addWindowListener(wndCloser);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    new SortTable();
  }
}
class TabModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  protected int sortCol = 0;

  protected boolean isSortAsc = true;

  protected int m_result = 0;
  protected int columnsCount = 1;
  Vector vector = new Vector();
  public TabModel() {
    vector.removeAllElements();
    vector.addElement(new Integer(3));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(504));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(1));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(4));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(4));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(7));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(9));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(78));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(654));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(91));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(718));
    vector.addElement(new Integer(62254));
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
Collections.sort(vector,new TabComparator(isSortAsc)); 
        return vector == null ? 0 : vector.size();
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnsCount;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    String str = "data";
    if (column == sortCol)
      str += isSortAsc ? " >>" : " <<";
    return str;
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int nRow, int nCol) {
    return false;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int nRow, int nCol) {
    if (nRow < 0 || nRow >= getRowCount())
      return "";
    if(nCol>1){
      return "";
    }
    return vector.elementAt(nRow);
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return "data ";
  }

  class ColumnListener extends MouseAdapter {
    protected JTable table;

    public ColumnListener(JTable t) {
      table = t;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
      int columnModelIndex = colModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
      int modelIndex = colModel.getColumn(columnModelIndex)
          .getModelIndex();

      if (modelIndex < 0)
        return;
      if (sortCol == modelIndex)
        isSortAsc = !isSortAsc;
      else
        sortCol = modelIndex;

      for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) { 
        TableColumn column = colModel.getColumn(i);
        column.setHeaderValue(getColumnName(column.getModelIndex()));
      }
      table.getTableHeader().repaint();

      Collections.sort(vector,new TabComparator(isSortAsc));
      table.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(TabModel.this));
      table.repaint();
    }
  }
}

class TabComparator implements Comparator {
  protected boolean isSortAsc;

  public TabComparator( boolean sortAsc) {
    isSortAsc = sortAsc;
  }

  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (!(o1 instanceof Integer) || !(o2 instanceof Integer))
      return 0;
    Integer s1 = (Integer) o1;
    Integer s2 = (Integer) o2;
    int result = 0;
    result = s1.compareTo(s2);
    if (!isSortAsc)
      result = -result;
    return result;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof TabComparator) {
        TabComparator compObj = (TabComparator) obj;
      return compObj.isSortAsc == isSortAsc;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 table sorting is built into the API. There is no need for all that custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is not the sorting itself, its the initial sorting state I'm concerned about.

Comment: I have edited the code. Try now, the table will be initially sorted.